# How to get the match number n ? regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have this html text :

```
<div>
     <div class="item1">  value 1 </div>
                \n
     <div class="item1">  value 2 </div>
               \n
     <div class="item1">  value 3 </div> 

</div>
```

there is unknown texts between the div tags:

I want to get `value 3`

I tried this: `re.findall(r'class="item1".*?{3}>(.*?)</div>',x,re.S)`

but I get invalid repeat error, because I user {3}, what to get just the third match ?

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regex! Use BeautifulSoup library to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through BeautifulSoup [css selectors](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors).

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> s = """<div>
     <div class="item1">  value 1 </div>

     <div class="item1">  value 2 </div>

     <div class="item1">  value 3 </div> 

</div>"""
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
>>> soup
<html><body><div>
<div class="item1">  value 1 </div>
<div class="item1">  value 2 </div>
<div class="item1">  value 3 </div>
</div></body></html>
>>> [i.string for i in soup.select('div > div[class~=item1]')[-1]]
['  value 3 ']
>>> [i.string.strip() for i in soup.select('div > div[class~=item1]')[-1]]
['value 3']
```

Like others said, don't parse html files with regex.

```
>>> re.findall(r'<div\s+class="item1">\s*(.*?)\s+</div>', s)[-1]
'value 3'
```

Comment: `[-1]` picks the last value from the list.

Comment: @david : Note that Avinash Raj's regex assumes there will always be at least one space after the value number. Although the regex solution is shorter than using BeautifulSoup, and it works ok for this relatively simple example, really you should use a proper HTML parse and avoid using regex on HTML.